# Eliminate white space margins from Matplotlib graph in Power BI Service

Tags: python, matplotlib, powerbi

I have an issue with white space margins of matplotlib graphs when these are published on Power BI service.

I can successfully generate the graph with minimal whitespace margins on PBI Desktop (image 1).

[image: Power BI 1]

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
data = dataset
x = data['Time Period']
y = data['Data Metric 4'].rolling(13).mean()
y1 = data['Data Metric 4'].rolling(1).sum()

plt.plot(x,y,linewidth = 6.0, color = 'orange')
plt.plot(x,y1,linewidth = 3.0)

plt.xticks(x, rotation = '60',fontsize = '8')

plt.xlabel("Time Period")
plt.ylabel("Data Metric")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

When publishing this graph on PBI Service(app.powerbi.com), I'll get the below result (image 2 attached). The red arrows show you the blank space. Ideally, I want to bring my graph in such a state like image 1.

[image: Power BI 2]

Can this somehow be fixed and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`plt.tight_layout()` takes three arguments. You want to set them all to 0.
Like `plt.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggested solution! Allow me a couple of days to test this on my dataset and I'll endeavour to post the results ASAP.

Comment: Great solution, it worked perfectly. Upvoted and marked as best answer :)